# openbravo on docker Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: docker

I use the reposetiory lukasz/docker-scala for installing openbravo  on Scala 2.10.3, Java 7 update 45, and sbt 0.13.1 on top of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

This is the way that I run the docker file :

```
############################################################ 
# Dockerfile to build openbaravo container images 
# Based on ubuntu:12.04 
############################################################ 
# Set the base image to Ubuntu 
FROM lukasz/docker-scala 
# File Author / Maintainer 
MAINTAINER SecuPi 
################## BEGIN INSTALLATION ###################### 
# Install 
RUN \ 
apt-get update && \ 
apt-get install -y python-software-properties && \ 
add-apt-repository ppa:openbravo-isv/ppa && \ 
apt-get update && \ 
apt-get upgrade -y && \ 
apt-get install -y openbravo-3 
##################### INSTALLATION END ##################### 
EXPOSE 80
```

I have tried to install the openBravo on docker image. 
And got the error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/openbravo-3_3.0.r26702.PR-15Q2.1-1precise1_all.deb (--unpack): 
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1 
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/openbravo-3_3.0.r26702.PR-15Q2.1-1precise1_all.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the image:

```
docker pull rotemsecupi/ubuntu1204-openbravo-new
```

And start a container:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 rotemsecupi/ubuntu1204-openbravo-new
```